# ansible loop through assert checks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible role that uses the following tasks to validate some of the rpms installed on a system.

```
---
- name: "[Misc - Validator] Load up user config for testing"
  command: yum list installed
  register: yum_listing

- name: "[Misc - Validator] Check for values"
  assert:
    that:
      - "{{item.check}} in  {{item.file}}.stdout_lines"
    loop:
      - { check: rsyncd, file: yum_listing }
    success_msg: "Misc RPMs installed"
    fail_msg: "Misc RPMs missing"
```

However ansible 2.12 is giving me issues saying:

```
TASK [tds_validation : [Misc - Validator] Check for values] *******************************************************************
fatal: [testhost-host01.example.net]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/roles/tds_validation/tasks/validators/tds_misc.yml': line 6, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: \"[Misc - Validator] Check for values\"\n  ^ here\n"}
```

This is just a simple example.  I would like to expand this to more checks in the loop and more possible registers to check.

I would expect to see it either OK or Changed.

Comment: Your loop is is not indented correctly. It should be at the same level as assert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment your loops is not indented correctly. Also, your don't need the curly brackets in `assert: that:`. You can do something like below:

Example of playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    packages: 
      - package1
      - package2
      - package3
    yum_listing: {
        "changed": true,
        "stdout_lines": [
            "package1",
            "package2"
        ]
    }

  tasks:
    - name: "[Misc - Validator] Check for values"
      assert:
        that:
          - item in yum_listing.stdout_lines
        success_msg: "Misc RPMs installed"
        fail_msg: "Misc RPMs missing"
      loop: "{{ packages }}"
```

Gives:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=package1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "package1",
    "msg": "Misc RPMs installed"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=package2) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "item": "package2",
    "msg": "Misc RPMs installed"
}
failed: [localhost] (item=package3) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "assertion": "item in yum_listing.stdout_lines",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "item": "package3",
    "msg": "Misc RPMs missing"
}
```

Comment: The tasks file in my role ended up looking like this:

---
- name: "[Misc - Validator] Load up user config for testing" 
  command: yum list installed
  register: yum_listing
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: "[Misc - Validator] Check for values"
  assert:
    that:
      - "'{{ item.check }}' in {{ item.file }}.stdout_lines"
    success_msg: "Misc RPMs installed"
    fail_msg: "Misc RPMs missing"
  loop:
    - { check: 'rsyncd', file: 'yum_listing' }
    - { check: 'htop', file: 'yum_listing' }
    - { check: 'screen', file: 'yum_listing' }